# Logger is null in asp.net app when run from a different directory

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core

I am trying to run an asp.net core web app on linux, and it works if I run it from its directory, but if I try to run it from a different directory I get a `NullReferenceException` from `Ilogger`.

I have a service defined like this

```cs
    public class GPIOOutput : Output
    {
        private ILogger<GPIOOutput> logger;
        private List<IGpioPin> pins;

        public GPIOOutput(IOptions<GPIOOptions> options, ILogger<GPIOOutput> logger)
            :base(options.Value.Pins.Count)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            pins = options.Value.Pins.Select(p => Pi.Gpio[p]).ToList();
            pins.ForEach(p => p.PinMode = GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
            UpdateOutput();
        }

        protected override void UpdateOutput()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pins.Count; i++)
            {
                pins[i].Write(!channelData[i]);
                logger.LogInformation(channelData[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

and I am adding it like this:

```cs
public static void AddGPIO(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var config = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            services.AddOptions<GPIOOptions>().Bind(config.GetSection("Hardware:GPIO"));
            services.AddSingleton<IOutput, GPIOOutput>();
        }
```

I built the project in self-contained mode and copied if to my raspberry pi. It is in `/home/pi/test`. when I run it like this it works:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd test
pi@raspberrypi:~/test $ sudo ./SmartHouse --urls "http://0.0.0.0:80/"
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/pi/test
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

but if I try from `/home /pi` like this I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ./test/SmartHouse --urls "http://0.0.0.0:80/"

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
   at SmartHouse.RPI.GPIO.GPIOOutput..ctor(IOptions`1 options, ILogger`1 logger) in E:\Efraim's souse\SmartHouse\RPI\GPIO\GPIOOutput.cs:line 22
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstruuctorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ISere callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingletnCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ISere callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstruuctorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ISere callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingletnCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ISere callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstruuctorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ISere callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransietCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ISere callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerrableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ISere callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstruuctorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ISere callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingletnCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ISere callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__Di_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Typpe, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Typpe)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredServicrovider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredServicceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToke
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken to shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken to
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at SmartHouse.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Efraim's stuff\SmartHouse\SmartHouse\Program.c
Aborted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue on my project. **If my project run command line while not in project folder(or publish folder) Kestrel didn't find any file from project or appsettings.json files... and appsettings.json values coming null and my application going down cause of this also didn't find any html content in my project...**

> I solved like this, I create a static prop on class in my Program.cs
>   and name is "PathDomain"

After that, I take Application path domain using this command

> **PathDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;**

```
        public static string PathDomain { get; set; }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PathDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Api started :)");

        }
```

> Here is come magic touch

In **IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder** method, I use UseContentRoot() method and pass my PathDomain variable to method

My method look something like this

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<ProjenInlineApiStartup>()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(PathDomain)//<------THIS IS THE LINE
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {

                    string CONFIG_SERVER_FILE = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONFIG_SERVER_FILE");
                    string RUN_PLATFORM = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RUN_PLATFORM");
                    string ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
                    Console.WriteLine("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: " + ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT);
                    Console.WriteLine("CONFIG_SERVER_FILE: "+ CONFIG_SERVER_FILE);
                    Console.WriteLine("RUN_PLATFORM: " + RUN_PLATFORM);

                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{RUN_PLATFORM}.json", true, true);

                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                    if (args != null)
                    {
                        config.AddCommandLine(args);
                    }
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, config) => { config.ClearProviders(); });
```

I hope it's help :)